# Use case example for copyToRealm() in Realm

Tags: realm

Could someone give a simple **use case** example **why** someone would use `copyToRealm()` instead of `createObject()` ?

It is not clear to me **why** and **when** would anyone use `copyToRealm()` if there is `createObject()`.

In the example here they seem pretty much the same https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/ .

`copyToRealm()` takes an unmanaged object and connects it to a Realm, while `createObject()` creates an object directly in a Realm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example it is very useful when you copy objects generated by GSON - returned from your Rest API into Realm.

Comment: So basically when I receive an object over the network and then I want to store that in Realm ?

Comment: Yes. You'll receive JSON, Gson lib will convert it into POJO object, and you will store it in Realm.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed makes sense.

Comment: According to the documentation, insert() resp. insertOrUpdate() is faster than copyToRealm() and should be preferred if you do not need the inserted objects directly afterwards, i.e. if you are currently not using the result of copyToRealm().

Answer (score 2):

`realm.createObject()` also returns a RealmProxy instance and is manipulated directly and therefore creates `N` objects to store `N` objects, however you can use the following pattern to use only `1` instance of object to store `N` objects:

```
    RealmUtils.executeInTransaction(realm -> {
        Cat defaultCat = new Cat(); // unmanaged realm object

        for(CatBO catBO : catsBO.getCats()) {
            defaultCat.setId(catBO.getId());
            defaultCat.setSourceUrl(catBO.getSourceUrl());
            defaultCat.setUrl(catBO.getUrl());
            realm.insertOrUpdate(defaultCat);
        }
    });
```

But to actually answer your question, `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` makes sense if you want to persist elements, put them in a `RealmList<T>` and set that RealmList of newly managed objects in another RealmObject. It happens mostly if your RealmObject classes and the downloaded parsed objects match.

```
@JsonObject
public class Cat extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @JsonField(name="id")
    String id;

    @JsonField(name="source_url")
    String sourceUrl;

    @JsonField(name="url")
    String url;

    // getters, setters;
}

final List<Cat> cats = //get from LoganSquare;
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        Person person = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
        RealmList<Cat> realmCats = new RealmList<>();
        for(Cat cat : realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(cats)) {
             realmCats.add(cat);
        }
        person.setCats(realmCats);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is `copyToRealm` in your sample?

Comment: @Divers a reasonable question, so I added an answer to that too.